# Single slit diffraction - wave vs particle view

Tags: diffraction, wave-particle-duality

If monochromatic light is shot through a single slit onto a screen, we can analyze the pattern on the screen using wave properties. This analysis is done assuming the wavelength is constant.

But with a particle view... there's uncertainty in the momentum after going through the slit... hence with DeBroglie's relation $p=\dfrac{h}{\lambda}$, uncertainty in the wavelength.

So is there any contradiction here... the first analysis has no uncertainty in wavelength (allowing us to calculate minimums and maximums using the wavelength of light and the width of the slit), the second view does have uncertainty in wavelength.

How does one reconcile these views?

EDIT: The impression I'm getting is that the magnitude of the momentum of the photon doesn't change... only the direction does. But with heisenberg's uncertainty principle:

$\Delta x\Delta p_{x}\ge \dfrac{\hbar}{2}$, can't I arbitrarily make the slit narrower and narrower, imparting greater and greater uncertainty to the momentum along that direction. Wouldn't the magnitude of the momentum of the photon change at some point?

Comment: What's there to reconcile? $h/\lambda$ isn't the uncertainty in the wavelength...

Comment: But if p is uncertain, then $\lambda$ is uncertain.

Comment: Diffraction doesn't have a "particle view". It's always waves that diffract.

Comment: @CuriousOne, so when monochromatic waves diffract, their wavelength remains fixed? there's no uncertainty in wavelength?

Comment: The *longitudinal* wavelength is exactly known, since one usually assumes the monochromatic plane wave comes from infinity. The *transverse* wavelength behind the slit is subject to uncertainty principle, since it is spatially limited by the slit.

Comment: Sure there is... it's given by the lifetime of the slit. Since no slit exists forever, there has to be an uncertainty on the energy, and with that on the wavelength, but in practice the slit introduces a much smaller uncertainty than the source, so we don't care about it. It's a fringe effect that usually doesn't have any physical meaning.

Comment: @CuriousOne, if there is a wave-particle duality, then there should be an equivalent explanation in both (dual) domains. The perception that there is an explanation in only one domain implies that there is a subtle 'magic' step (a quick hand wave passes over the difficult area maybe) such that one can get 'quantised' diffraction patterns from the wave analysis. These abstract mathematical ideals are great for hiding such issues.

Comment: @PhilipOakley Diffraction can be explained on a particle basis with individual coherent photons. It’s a light wave that cannot be explained without incorporating individual photon particles. Photons passing through a slit will both diffract around and behind the edges or Scatter away from the edges. Photons will cover the screen left and right of the slit and the math shows that coherent photons traveling from the left edge and the right edge will interfere with each other destructively at the minimums on the screen. See “Single Edge certainty” at billalsept.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [following quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon) is relevant to whether in quantum mechanical terms there exists a monochromaticity possible , i.e. exact knowledge of momentum for the photon:

[image]

instead of a slit, there is an electron.

So the problem "photon impinging on slit" is a quantum mechanical problem, and there exists an uncertainty on the momentum of the impinging photon from the Heisenberg Uncertainty,  and an uncertainty in the size of the slit due to the fact that it is defined by quantum mechanical objects like the outer electrons of the sides of the slit.

It is a scattering problem and could in principle be solved , but the HUP allows for estimates rather than going through the complicated mathematics of solving for the scattering.

Each individual photon may be elastically scattered, but its momentum is uncertain within the HUP of the wavelength times momentum and the scatter will be uncertain to that extent.

The classical view with the quantum mechanical are reconciled because h is such a small number that the HUP is easily satisfied.

Comment: So does any light matter interaction generally result in a shift in wavelength of the light (compton effect basically?)

Comment: No, not compton effect, although it has a probability. Difractions refraction reflection are mostly elastic, within the HUP boundaries of not being able to pin down individual photon energy except within HUP.

Comment: so diffraction immediately causes uncertainty in wavelength? so the idea of monochromatic light, remaining monochromatic after diffraction is really just a classical idea?

Comment: it is not diffraction that is causing it, it is that there is no monochromaticity really, as the quoted thought experiment shows. It is because QM is probabilistic

Answer (score 1):

There's not necessarily uncertainty in the wavelength of the particle. The magnitude of the momentum vector could be the same for every particle, but its direction could be different. The particle's speed is certain, but the direction it heads in is not.

In real light and particle sources, however, there is always uncertainty in the wavelength. Even lasers emit a small range of wavelengths instead of being monochromatic.

Comment: Assume the source is monochromatic. So suppose, the slit is located along the y-axis. The photon goes through the slit. We know its y-coordinate... so there's an uncertainty in the momentum along the y-axis. But the magnitude of the net momentum of the photon doesn't change through the slit?

Comment: @AmeetSharma You are correct aside from a small error: if the slit is parallel to the y-axis, then the particle's **x**-position is restricted, causing the uncertainty in the **x**-momentum to increase.

Comment: Can't I arbitrarily make the slit narrow restricting the position more and more, making the momentum of the photon along that axis have greater and greater uncertainty? wouldn't this change the magnitude of the momentum of the photon?

Comment: The only thing that would change the magnitude of the momentum would be if the particle impacted the edges of the slit. Otherwise, its momentum doesn't change other than direction.

Comment: @MarkH hmm. it is a quantum mechanical world there. The "slit +photon" boundary value solution, and "hit" just means "probability of scattering". The photon can scatter from the middle of the slit as well as the edge, following a probability distribution which is roughly described by the HUP.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the photon or electron moves in the xy plane along the y direction. A screen is paced in the xz plane with a slit of width dx. The particle is constrained to the width of the slit, hence after the screen there is an uncertainty in $p_x$. This uncertainty can be calculated from the wave function and is actually the probability distribution that produces the pattern.

You can say that the single slit diffraction pattern visualizes the uncertainty. Note that if the transmission of the slit is not a rect function but a gaussian, then the interference pattern is also a Gaussian. This corresponds more closely to the popular image of uncertainty.

Answer (score -2):

There is definitely change in p>h/dx. But if the slit is 10 nm (not possible practically) and h=7.10^-34 you get dp=10^-25. This so low that is absolutely monochromatic.

Comment: This is wrong. The absolute value of the momentum/wave vector does not change.

Comment: If the absolute value of momentum does not change the particle would follow a straight line. As it impinges on a stationary object conservation of momentum implies that when p of particle changes direction than p of the wall - slit also changes from p=0 to p final. If p wall - slits stays 0 than p of particle can not change direction. Now while p wall slit is changed p final of the particle should be smaller as an absolute value than p initial.

Comment: "If the absolute value of momentum does not change the particle would follow a straight line." This is wrong.

Comment: Mathematical prove:


Let a rigid body has Px=Py=0. 


The particle initial px=0, py=g. As direction is changed -  px changes to s


Before impact
px=0 py=g abs.val. --  p=g particle
P=0 body
Total momentum of the system P+p=g



After impact denote abs value of P - Pa; abs. val of p ---pa
px=s
Px=-s Pa=s
pa+Pa=g law of p total conservation 
pa=g-s relation proved!!!!



The only way pa not to change is when Pa=0 which is impossible even if the mass of the body is considered! infinite hence its v=0  but you must multiply 0.inf = Pa not 0.

Comment: This is in fact Newtons 1 Law in some disguise. If the particle follows not a straight line it has interacted with another body.

Comment: I am afraid that there is some confusion. The momentum changes direction, but not size since energy is conserved. This is what happens with diffraction. I have neglected recoil energy as is it incredibly small. @mercury

Comment: Energy is conserved but not that of the particle but of the total system of corse = particle + walls. The walls must take part of the energy as it will move backward to px. Change in p and E of the particles are very very very small but not 0. I insisted that in my answer. Nevertheless Heisenberg gives only a lower limit for px max of p=10^-25 kg.m/s. I dont know what is the upper limit for dp. So abs. value of p after impact is p-s and s = px which can be 10^-25 or more according to HUP. Do you agree? Thank you anyway for interest.

Comment: If the screen is made of 1000g of iron the recoil energy is 1000*6e+23*2000* times smaller than the kinetic energy of the particle, so utterly negligible would be an understatement.

Comment: And IF the first statement in your answer were true, which it isn't, then the third statement would still be wrong. @mercury

Comment: My first statement is the HUP. Do you think it is wrong? About third statement I don't know what you mean. HUP says that after the slit p can increase over a limit. If this happens I can not see how is the interaction without change of the absolute value of p.

Comment: From the context I assume that by $p$ you mean the absolute value, and this does not change. As for the 3d sentence, the numerical value of dp should be of the order of p or no diffraction would be observable. @mercury

Comment: In my answer p=h/dx is of course dpx (sorry for not being precise). But I don't see why py would change. There is no slit in y direction to apply HUP in y direction. So py must stay constant and this leads to the change in abs. value of $p=\sqrt{p_{x}^{2}+p_{y}^{2}}$. As a matter of fact dp would about 10^-25 and one can easily say it doesn't change. That is the statement in my answer.

Comment: Not if $p$ is also 10$^{-25}$. So how much is $p$?

Comment: As the recoil energy is utterly negligible the energy of the electron/ photon is conserved, so $p$ is constant. $dp_x$ should be sizeable compared to $p$ or there is no observable diffraction. A slit of 10 nm is realizable with electron beam lithography.

Comment: In elastic scattering of a light particle from a heavy body px (initially= 0) can get = p initial,(=py) e.g. scattering at 90 grade. This has nothing to do with HUP. HUP is on top of this elastic scattering (ES). It is not possible to explain (even include) ES in a slit scattering and thats why it is treated as diffraction.